# SQL Statement with OR not showing both cases

Tags: sql, db2

I found out about a bug in my application, where the sql statement isn't displaying the correct result. I wan't every transaction from a table that gone from OR to an specific iban:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM BANKING.TRANSTAB                                                            
 WHERE ABSENDER = 'DE71419330598239161300'                                    
         OR EMPF = 'DE71419330598239161300'                                           
         AND                                                                          
         TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2018-10','YYYY-MM')                                    
         AND TO_DATE('2018-12','YYYY-MM');                                            
------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---
  ROW_ID  ABSENDER                EMPF                                     SUMME  ZWECK   
------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---
      98  DE71419330598239161300  DE38820942858809256538                   10.45  test    
      99  DE71419330598239161300  DE38820942858809256538                   23.42  test    
     102  DE71419330598239161300  DE38820942858809256538                   12.00  123     
     103  DE71419330598239161300  DE38820942858809256538                   12.00  12      
     104  DE71419330598239161300  DE38820942858809256538                   12.00  123     
     105  DE71419330598239161300  DE38820942858809256538                  123.00  123
```

It is currently just displaying transactions that came from the selected iban altough the truth is that there are also transactions incoming:

```
 106  DE38820942858809256538  DE71419330598239161300                    1.00  spufitest     
 107  DE38820942858809256538  DE71419330598239161300                    1.00  Spufitest     
 108  DE38820942858809256538  DE71419330598239161300                    1.00  spufgitest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OR you need to use inside bracket all OR conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM BANKING.TRANSTAB                                                            
     WHERE (ABSENDER = 'DE71419330598239161300'                                    
     OR EMPF = 'DE71419330598239161300')
     AND                                                                          
     TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2018-10','YYYY-MM')                                    
     AND TO_DATE('2018-12','YYYY-MM');
```

Comment: This is giving me 0 rows back.

Comment: @bastel That's mean you don't have any transactions between '2018-10' and '2018-12' TIME for ABSENDER OR EMPF 'DE71419330598239161300'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My time query is wrong. How can I search for the month when the time is in this format:  2018-12-02-02.47.29.987903 ?

Comment: What is the datatype of the  "Time" column in the table BANKING.TRANSTAB

Comment: @bastel - Search for your month range by `time >= TO_DATE('2018-10','YYYY-MM') AND time < TO_DATE('2019-01','YYYY-MM')`.  Always query (and store) date/time/timestamp types with an explicit exclusive upper-bound, and avoid `BETWEEN`.  Your original, inclusive, upper-bound was actually `'2018-12-01T00:00:00.000000'`, which is wrong for two reasons (obviously doesn't include all of December, and inclusiveness means events at midnight might be included twice).